# MultiPage Form Identify VBA

Tags: forms, vba, multipage

it might be the silliest question anyone ever asked, but I have been looking for a long time and I could not find an answer.

I have a form with a multipage with 2 pages, and I want to know which page is the one the user is filling up when he presses the ComandButton (which page is the user viewing at that moment). I want that because depends on which page the data will be inserted in diferent place.

If more info is needed, just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: The multipage control has a value. Read that value, and you have your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a control called `MultiPage1` you could return the page as below

For example

```
`1st tab
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0
`3rd tab
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 2
```

Comment: Sorry I dont get it, I want to use a "if" statment to clasify, so it would be like that? If Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0 then 'statment end, or how?. Please if you could post a simple example using "if" I'd be grateful, anyway I really appreciate your answer. Thanks

Comment: So if `If Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0` the the user is on the first page, if `If Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1` then the user is on the second page etc. Does that help?

Comment: another question:     The word  "Me" is it necessary in this case? I dont have a clue when I need to use and when no

Comment: No - you can just use `MultiPage1.Value`. Using `Me` does give you VBA intellisense (autocomplete) though